# Sending Email with Godaddy server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a PHP script that can send email in local test environment. I am using Google SMTP server for that. But when I use the same code to send email with Godaddy server, I am not getting any email.

This is the PHP code I am using

```
if (empty($errorMessage)) {
        function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body)
        {
            global $error;
            $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
            $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
            $mail->DKIM_domain = '127.0.0.1';
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
            $mail->Host = 'localhost';
            $mail->Port = 465;

            $mail->Username = GUSER;
            $mail->Password = GPWD;
            $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->AddAddress($to);

            if (!$mail->Send()) {
                //$error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
                return false;
            } else {
                //$error = 'Message sent!';
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (smtpmailer("testuser@gmail.com", $email, $name, $subject, $message)) {
            array_push($successMessage, "Message is send successfully");
        } else {
            array_push($mailErrorMessage, "Error sending your message, please try again");
        }
    }
```

This is the error message I am getting

```
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<sdfsdf@dfdsfds.com>
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<testuser@gmail.com>
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 08:59:00 +0000
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: testuser@gmail.com
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: sdfdsf <sdfsdf@dfdsfds.com>
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: sdfdsf
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <07861decb0a3210648608f6e6b5db395@thedomain.com>
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.24 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: dsfdfsf
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Message denied for spoofing attempt via SMTP Auth (From address: sdfdsf <sdfsdf@dfdsfds.com> IP: 127.0.0.1 AuthenticatedID: contact@thdeomain.com Account owner: theowner)
2017-08-18 08:59:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-08-18 08:59:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 md-59.webhostbox.net closing connection
```

I do not know if it is the issue with PHPMailer or mail server

Comment: Are the last three lines of your log output not clear?

Comment: It says Message denied for spoofing attempt. But I am sending the email with the username and password for the email account I created

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack explains what spoofing is. So the conclusion is, it is an issue of mailserver from Godaddy.

Comment: It's saying you're spoofing because you're spoofing - your *from* address is not the same as your account address. Top suggestion: don't spoof.

Comment: I got the answer for this question from this stackoverflow question. This solved the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507989/php-mailer-message-denied-for-spoofing-attempt-via-smtp-auth